# What happens with sulfur dioxide reacts with dimethyl trisulfide? What compounds are left over?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have only found one single reference to this reaction online which states $\ce{SO2}$ will destroy DMTS ($\ce{C2H6S3}$), but I cannot find a reference as to what may be happening or what may be left over. 
Can anyone help me solve this? I'm not a scientist or student. I'm actually a home brewer trying to reduce DMTS in a finished beer by potentially adding $\ce{SO2}$, but I don't want worse compounds left over.